# If Statement in my where clause with dates

Tags: sql, if-statement, where-clause, dateadd

for whatever reason, I can't use weekday functions in SQL at my organization, so am needing some help with a workaround. I have a SQL code which is supposed to query the previous weekday. So this is what we currently use:

```
select p.businessDate, p.accountNumber (more fields, but unecessary)
from Table p, 
where p.businessDate = dateadd(DAY, -1, today())
```

The problem is on Mondays, this query pulls data from Sunday, when we need it for Friday. Is there a way to get around using dateadd(WEEKDAY, -1, today())? This code is run automatically, Mon-Fri, daily.

Comment: are you allowed to use `DATEPART`?

Comment: Yes, I believe I should be able to!

Comment: What database are you working in? ie. Sql server, MySql, etc.

Comment: An examples of what you mean by "weekday function"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you said you can use `DATEPART`, the case statement checks if the current day is Monday, if it is, it subtracts 3 days to get Friday, else it subtracts 1 day, `DATEPART` returns a numeric value starting with 1 for Sunday and moves to 7 for Saturday, so as Monday is the date of concern we check for the value of 2, this is **SQL Server** syntax.

```
select p.businessDate, p.accountNumber (more fields, but unecessary)
from Table p, 
where businessDate = CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) = 2 
THEN DATEADD(DAY, -3, GETDATE()) 
ELSE DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) END
```

`DATEPART` documentation - [datepart-transact-sql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Thank you! This exactly answered my question! Appreciate the prompt response!

Comment: @shadaet You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I found something [here](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/if-today-is-monday-show-friday-to-sunday) that I think can help you.

If you can use `DATENAME` then you can check if the name of the current date is `'Monday'`. If it is, then instead of `dateadd(DAY, -1, today())` you can do `dateadd(DAY, -3, today())`.